# Adding an image to ListTile in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

So I have this ListView in Flutter with ListTile inside of it:

```
return ListView.separated(
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            print("nameList: $nameList");

            Name name = nameList[index];
           
            return Container(
              color: Colors.white60,
              
              child: ListTile(
                 
                  title: Text(name.name, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30)),
                  subtitle: Text(
                    "Calories: ${name.age}\nProfession: ${name.profession}",
                   
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
```

What I would like to do is add an image (with a placeholder icon on it) in a small square (inside a container?) to the ListTile that has onTapped (which would invoke getImage from Image Picker). Also, it would be great if it was possible to add a little row of large text beside it ('LARGE' in the image example). As always, the simples solutions are always the toughest for me. What's the way to do it most efficiently?

[image: example image]

Comment: Have you tried [trailing](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile/trailing.html) property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the icon by trailing property in ListTile,
if you want  you need to style like the image i suggest not use ListTile,you should desgin with Row and Column

```
Container(
          child: ListTile(
            title: Text("Title"),
            subtitle:Text("Categories"),
            trailing: GestureDetector(onTap: (){
              ///do something heres
            
            },child: Container(height:30,width:50,color:Colors.amber,child: Icon(Icons.add))),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: Yeah, that's probably the way to go, it really needs to be ListTile since I have a lot of items, and it would probably be the best way to do it. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 2):

If you add any widget with ontap feature in trailing, you can do it.

```
         ListTile(
            trailing: InkWell(
            onTap: (){},
            child: Container(
            child: Image(),
          ),
        )
         )
```